# Mysql replace list of columns from another table

Tags: mysql, replace, find-in-set

this is an example, it's similar to my project

i have two tables no link between Table1 and Table2.
TABLE1

```
    id! LIST(string)!             FNAME!       lNAME ! postalcode! country!
    1!  (FNAME lNAME, postalCode) ! fname1!   lname1! 02116!       USA!
    2!  (FNAME lNAME, postalCode) ! fname2!   lname2! 90210!       USA! 
    3!  (FNAME lNAME)             ! fname3!   lname3! 75000!       FR!
    4!  (FNAME lNAME)             ! fname4!   lname4! 13000!       FR!
    5!  (FNAME postalCode)        ! fname5!   lname5! 41000!       DE!

ect...
```

TABLE2.NAME Contains all the elements of the TABLE1

```
    NAME!  NAMEOCDE!
    02116! 10!
    90210! 11!
    75000! 12!
    13000! 13!
    41000! 14!
    fname1! 15!
    fname2! 16!
    fname3! 17!
    fname4! 18!
    fname5! 17!
    lname1! 19!
    lname2! 20!
    lname3! 21!
   lname4! 22!
  lname5! 23!
ect...
```

I want to replace Table1.LIST by  TABLE2.NAMECODE
CAN I DO THIS BY:

- Query whitout trigger or procedure
- Any solution with mysql I have already done with PHP
- **Join theses tables**

Note :
The Table1.LIST may be different
The Table1 contains a lot of columns
Table1.LIST is the same for each country 
thanks

Comment: Is there any link between Table1 and Table2?

Comment: There is no any  link between these 2 tables but all the data of table1 are in table 2

Comment: It would be possible to do this if list was the same for all - but since mysql does not have split string function then a procedure would be necessary.

Comment: to  P.Salmon: If the list is the same for each country

I have update my question